# important vector bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

I was wondering if any vector bundles on a manifold other than the tangent bundle give topological invariants. I guess stiefel Whitney classes also come from the inverse bundle - but other than that.

Comment: somewhat related question (in the algebraic context): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57682/natural-coherent-sheaves-on-algebraic-varieties

Comment: On a spin manifold, the associated bundle to the spin representation is a natural home for some topological invariants - is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: The grothendieck group of *all* vector bundles on $X$ modulo exact sequences is the K-theory of $X$, and hence a topological invariant. 

But in general, only the tangent bundle and bundles constructed from it are naturally associated to a "naked" manifold. 

Comment: sure do you have a reference?

the more I think about it the more I realize that this is a vague question. The thought was that if one looks at all vector bundles and their Euler classes that one might pick up something other than the Euler characteristic and maybe even get some important submanifolds through tranverse self intersection of the zero section of the bundle.




Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top exterior power of the tangent bundle determines orientablility (the most basic of topological invariants, after dimension) in the sense that $\wedge^nTM$ is a trivial line bundle iff $M^n$ is orientable.

The complexified tangent bundle $TM\otimes_{\mathbf{R}} \mathbf{C}$ is used to define the [Pontryagin classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_class), which are themselves smooth invariants (although the Pontryagin numbers and the rational Pontryagin classes turn out to be topological invariants).

Both of these examples are built from the tangent bundle, so I suspect are not what you are looking for. Aside from this you could look at the stable normal bundle (as you suggest) or put some additional structure on your manifold (as Paul Siegel suggest in his comment).